# How to get the title of the thickest book from XML-file via Xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML-file with next structure:

```
<Books>
  <Book Topic="Databases" eBook = "Available">
    <Pablisher>Wrox</Pablisher>
    <Title>Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Integration Services: Problem, Design, Solution</Title>
    <Authors>
      <Author>Erik Veerman</Author>
      <Author>Jessica M. Moss</Author>
      <Author>Brian Knight</Author>
      <Author>Jay Hackney</Author>
    </Authors>
      <ISBN>978-0-470-52576-0</ISBN>
      <Pages>480</Pages>
      <PublicationDate>November 2009</PublicationDate>
      <Price>49.99</Price>
  </Book>
  </Books>
```

There are a lot of books and i have to return the title of the thickest one. 
The only thing i know is how to find max num of pages:

```
max(for $x in doc("C:\XMLFile1.xml")/Books/Book/Pages
return $x)
```

But next step is absolutely unclear to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you can return the book with the most pages. But the thickest you would have to know the width of the book or the thickness of the paper and covers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is take that max value and find a book that it is a part of

```
let $doc =     doc("C:\XMLFile1.xml")
let $pages := max($doc/Books/Book/Pages)
 return $doc/Books/book[Pages = $pages]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a single XPath expression:

```
/Books/Book[. is /Books/Book[Pages = max(/Books/Book/Pages)]]
```